# get the value of a varibale inside inline javascript

Tags: php, xpath

i am building web app and at some point i need to scrape the value of variable called `fid` from remote page this variable present in script like this:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript">fid="mytarget"; v_width=640; v_height=360;</script>
```

i have tried using xpath and i come with the code below:

```
$fid = $xpath->xpath_query("/body/script[contains(local-name(), 'fid')]", 1)->nodeValue;
```

but no luck

any help appretaited

Comment: Show this HTML page, and show a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to guess most of your input document and code. I doubt that `body` is the outermost element of that HTML document though.

A meaningful Xpath expression to search for this `script` element would be

```
//script[contains(., 'fid')]
```

This will find `script` element anywhere in the document if their text content includes `fid`. By the way: `local-name()` returns the local part of the name of the context node - which is not what you want.

---

**EDIT**

So, assuming the following document (please do not post code as links!):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body class="contentpane">
    <script type="text/rocketscript">fid="mytarget"; v_width=640; v_height=360;</script>
    <script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="http://remotesite.com/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can retrieve the value of `fid` with

```
substring-before(substring-after(//*[local-name() = 'script' and contains(.,'fid')],'='),';')
```

which will return

```
"mytarget"
```

Without the quotes:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//*[local-name() = 'script' and contains(.,'fid')],'"'),'"')
```

Caveat: In some environments, double quotes must be represented differently.

There is a *namespace* in your document and the path expression above is *ignoring* that namespace. The proper way to address this would be to *register* this namespace and use a *prefix* in the path expression.

Comment: here is the html code http://pastebin.com/FbVRTjkC i want to the text value of fid

Comment: So, what _exactly_ is the expected output? `mytarget`?

Comment: Thanks Very Much this works and gets the fid value without quotes

Comment: sorry for begging for this after long time but your solution works only if the html is perfectly formatted which is not the case always and sometime the html misses some elements and in this case the above solution doesn't work do u have any work around this?

Comment: @sherifhalim This path expression does not rely on a specific structure of the input document - it is already quite generic. What do you mean by "the HTML sometimes misses some elements"?